# executeScript() and executeAsyncScript() of javascriptExecutor interface is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, asynchronous-javascript

I know that `executeScript()` function of JavascriptExecutor interface in selenium requires no signalling mechanism and **it executes javascript inside it as synchronous(single threaded).**

While `executeAsyncScript()` function of JavascriptExecutor interface requires signalling mechanism in the form of callback i.e. arguments[arguments.length-1] and **it executes javascript inside it as asynchronously(multithreaded) without blocking main selenium code.**

This means that if there is sleep in executeScript() javascript code then it will wait for that sleep time **then execute further selenium statements**. While if there is sleep in executeAsyncScript(), it will execute main selenium code **in parallel to that sleep without blocking main code.**

Now consider following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        
    
        System.out.println("1");
        String javascript="var callback=arguments[arguments.length-1]; window.setTimeout(callback,15000);";  //callback has no problem here. Statement:1
        js.executeScript(javascript);  //Statement:2
        
        System.out.println("2");
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Now when I execute this code **it does not wait** for 15 sec sleep and immediately prints 2 and quit the browser while ideally it should behave synchronously i.e. it should block the main thread for 15 sec and after that it should print the 2 and quit the browser.

Now if I replace the statements 1 and 2 in above code with:

```
String javascript="var callback=arguments[arguments.length-1]; window.setTimeout(callback,15000);";
js.executeAsyncScript(javascript);
```

as:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        
    
        System.out.println("1");
    
    String javascript="var callback=arguments[arguments.length-1]; window.setTimeout(callback,15000);";
    
    js.executeAsyncScript(javascript);
    
    System.out.println("2");
    
    driver.quit();
    }
```

If I run above code **it waits for 15 sec** sleep and print 2 after 15 sec and quit the browser after printing 2 after that 15 sec sleep.

Why they are behaving oppositely?